# appending new datetime record each time the class is ran

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, append, project

i am trying to keep record of how many times and wen the code below is run, but every time i run it, it always adds the current time overriding the previous one. more like logs, but to be saved in dataframe.
the objective is to also capture the successful or failure of the compilation in that same df.

```
class track:
    def tracker(self):
        start_time = dt.now()
        #do something here
        return start_time

        
    def create_dataframe(self):
    
        tracktime = self.tracker()
    
        # create empty pandas df
        pdf = pd.DataFrame(index =['index'] ,columns= ['Date'])
    

        # convert to pyspark df
        sdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pdf)

        sdf = sdf.withColumn('Date',lit(str(tracktime.date())))
        sdf = sdf.withColumn('Time',lit(str(tracktime.time())))
        sdf.show()
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = track()
        p.create_dataframe()
```

[image: here are my results]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see all the dependencies so i cannot run your code, but you should look at [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) method for DataFrame class.

Comment: i did, the problem is, when i run the cass, it always creates a new df and thus keep only one record...maybe if i could define a df construct outside the function